# testing in a while loop (MARIE)

Tags: assembly, marie

I'm trying to write a while loop, while N > 5.

While I understand just making a loop point and jumping back to it, how should I write a skipcond test for N > 5?

I looked at the one other MARIE question regarding while loops, but didn't quite get an answer out of it.

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention my idea was to subtract 5 from N, then skipcond 800 to see if it is true or not. Is this a proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what a while loop close to yours & looks like in marie, see if by looking at this helps you any or post what you have so far and I will help you.  Regarding your question, subtracting 5 from N after you write  Loop, Load N , should work just fine.

```
 X := 1;
    while X < 10 do
 X := X + 1;
   endwhile;
```

----- Marie Code of above

```
ORG 100
Load One
Store X /Initialize X
Loop, Load X /Load loop constant
Subt Ten /Compare X to 10
SkipCond 000 /If AC<0 (X is less than 10), continue loop
Jump Endloop /If X is not less than 10, terminate loop
Load X /Begin body of loop
Add One /Add 1 to X
Store X /Store new value in X
Jump Loop /Continue loop
Endloop, Halt /Terminate program
X, Dec 0 /Storage for X
One, Dec 1 /The constant value 1
Ten, Dec 10 /The loop constant
```